# How to implement proxy server setting in selenium webdriver using java

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, proxy

```
I have tried both the below code but unable to set proxy
    Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
    proxy.setHttpProxy("socks5://localhost:8080");
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("--proxy-server= proxy");
    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("url");
```

or      ChromeOptions chromeOption= new ChromeOptions();
WebDriverManager.chromedriver().proxy("socks5://localhost:8080").setup();
WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver(chromeOption);
driver.get("url");

Comment: Welcome. It's helpful to provide as much detail in your question as possible to get a good answer. Can you add the error messages you get when you use this code? What makes it unsuccessful?

Answer (score 1):

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
String proxyadd = "176.9.119.170:8080";
Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
proxy.setHttpProxy(proxyadd);
proxy.setSslProxy(proxyadd);
chromeOptions.setCapability("proxy", proxy);
WebDriver driver  = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

There is a proxy class that can be used to set proxy including sock

https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/Proxy.html

Comment: eg: proxy.setSocksProxy("127.0.0.1:5555")